# Using internal regulator DVDD pin to power up external devices

Tags: microcontroller, led, voltage-regulator, analog, integrated-circuit

I am designing a H-Bridge PCB and using [DRV8323](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8320r.pdf) as the driver. This chip has a pin name `DVDD` which from my understanding, from the below statement, is used to provide 3.3 volt to internal circuitry of the chip. And they were generous enough to expose this to the out-side world.

> 3.3-V internal regulator output. Connect a X5R or X7R, 1-µF, 6.3-V ceramic capacitor between the DVDD and AGND pins. This regulator can
>   source up to 30 mA externally.

So I have 2 questions!

1) Did I understand the function of this pin correctly?

2) Can I use this pin to power up a SMD 0603 LED? The chip can be enabled/disabled by a GPIO from MCU and I think the LED will be a good way to indicate if the chip is in enabled or not. If so, what resistor I should use? To not draw more than 30mA I guess I need something like 150 OHM?

Comment: It depends on purpose colour and brightness 30mA to 3.2V LED is 3.3 Ohms,  20 mA to 2.1V LED is 60 Ohms while 120 Ohm to 2.1V LED is 10mA but then again 3mA is enough for an indicator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes - you understood it correctly. The internal regulator needs external decoupling capacitor for stability, so the voltage is available on a pin and as a nice side effect you can use up to 30mA from that regulator.
2. Assume 2V forward voltage of the diode, aim for 10mA (should be bright enough) and apply Ohm's law: R = U / I = (3.3 - 2.0)[V] / 0.01 [A] = 130 [Ohm]. A 150 Ohm resistor should be good enough. [Or use any of the available calculators.](http://led.linear1.org/1led.wiz)